# it runs with eclipse but it doesn't with the terminal

Tags: java, eclipse, terminal

I've created two java classes: Tools.java and tries.java (Contains the main()) and both are located in the same folder, namely src.

Everything went perfectly inside eclipse, but when I tried to run the script via the Terminal as the following:

javac src/tries.java

I got the error message:

```
src/tries.java:13: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Tools
location: class tries
        Tools rm = new Tools(path);
```

So it seems that it couldn't find the other class(Tools.java), which i don't understand!

Thank you in Advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the `src` folder to your classpath

```
javac -cp ./src src/tries.java
```

or step into src and call

```
javac -cp ./ tries.java
```

Comment: thanks, now it complains about imported classes in the Tools.java??

Comment: Then you have to add the third party jars to your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

This is a `class-path` issue put your `src/` folder in `class-path`